# CSS solution for changing background image on mouse hover and reverting on hover off

Tags: css, html

This is a uni project, I have three CD images that spin and play a song on mousehover but I want to change the background image too. I have managed to do that but when I hover off the cd image the background and song continues to play. If I put my mouse on the nav bar it will go back to the normal background. I would like to revert background to original after the cursor leaves the cd. I am new to this so a dumbed down explanation would be appreciated.

```
<head>
    <title>Learning HTML</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    <script src="main.js"></script>

</head>

    <body id="bg">



<div id="imagesMain">

  <div class="imagesMain__item" onmouseover="PlaySound('mySound')" 
onmouseout="StopSound('mySound')">
    <div class="imagesMain__item__bg" style="background-image: url(images/bg1.png)"></div>
    <img id="album1" src="images/album1.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="imagesMain__item" onmouseover="PlaySound('smallThings')" 
onmouseout="StopSound('smallThings')">
    <div class="imagesMain__item__bg" style="background-image: url(images/bg2.png)"></div>
    <img id="album2" src="images/album2.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="imagesMain__item" onmouseover="PlaySound('firstDate')" 
onmouseout="StopSound('firstDate')">
    <div class="imagesMain__item__bg" style="background-image: url(images/bg1.png)"></div>
    <img id="album3" src="images/album3.png" />
  </div>
```

```
<audio id='mySound' src='sounds/blink182-%5BAudioTrimmer.com%5D.mp3'/>
<audio id='smallThings' src='sounds/blink-182%20-%20All%20The%20Small%20Things-%5BAudioTrimmer.com%5D.mp3'/>
<audio id='firstDate' src='sounds/blink-182%20-%20First%20Date-%5BAudioTrimmer.com%5D.mp3'/>





</body>
```

CSS is as follows:

```
#imagesMain {
padding: 0;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: 300px;
text-align: center;
}
.imagesMain__item {
display: inline-block;
height: 300px;
position: relative;
width: 300px;
}
.imagesMain__item img {
cursor: pointer;
display: block;
height: 100%;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
z-index: 100;
}
.imagesMain__item__bg {
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 50% 50%;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
opacity: 0;
position: fixed;
transition: all ease-in-out 0.1s;
transform: scale(0);
right: 0;
top: 0;
} 
.imagesMain__item:hover img {
animation-name: rotate; 
animation-duration: 0.8s; 
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-timing-function: linear;
}
.imagesMain__item:hover .imagesMain__item__bg {
opacity: 1;
transform: scale(1);
}

@keyframes rotate {
from {transform: rotate(0deg);}
to {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}


html {
height: 100%;
}
body {
background-image: url(images/bg.png);
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: please share the IMPORTANT parts of your files. the js file main.js and the css file main.css are completly missing. but you show us the body-end-tag thats not important for the question ;)

Comment: CSS is there, the jS file is just playing the song but I'm looking for a css solution not a JS one.

Comment: OT: js inside of html should be avoided! BTT: just set a new picture within the :hover section in your css file. Where do you struggle?

Comment: It's working as intended for the hover and is changing the image on hover but I want it to go back to normal when I stop hovering but that is not the case, the image stays the same.

Comment: Shouldn't be. Can you provide a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) where we can see your issue?

Comment: I guess you won't see because the images are not there.. but here is the fiddle. First time using it so sorry if it's wrong. http://jsfiddle.net/ya8dxh80/

Comment: Here is a video, on hover off you can see background stays the same until I go to another cd but I want the background to go back to original before any hovers. https://youtu.be/gMfw8VREl_A

Comment: ok. the problem is you hover target! You should set it on the small rotating images and not on the whole item element.

Comment: Thanks Josh, how might one do that? :)

Comment: posted an answer. If you like it mark it as the asnwer. If you have any further questions please feel free to ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your html setup: change the occurence of the image and the bg-container.

```
<div class="imagesMain__item">
    <img id="album1" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/d/6/9/a/11970932001393807721BenBois_Vinyl_records.svg.hi.png" />
    <div class="imagesMain__item__bg" style="background-image: url(https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/ar0/7ae6e40453913321b8badf504f192e16)"></div>
</div>
```

Now set the hover handler on the rotation item and not on the whole item container.

```
.imagesMain__item > img:hover {
    animation-name: rotate; 
    animation-duration: 0.8s; 
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}
.imagesMain__item > img:hover + .imagesMain__item__bg {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
}
```

You can see it here in action: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Kasalop/ssuk07hp/)

Comment: This is ace, thanks Josh! Now i'll sit and figure it out so I understand. Thank you.